# How to bind Json response to class using volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

In my application, I want to bind `Json response` to a target class using `Volley library`, But am not able to do that.

My Code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    registerComponentDownload(GalleryParser.class, Const.api.URL_GALLERY);
}//on create

private void makeJsonObjectRequest(final Class<? extends BaseModel> className, String urlJsonArry) {

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,urlJsonArry,null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            //start gallery activity
        }
    } , new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
}
private void registerComponentDownload(Class<? extends BaseModel> aClass, String url) {
    makeJsonObjectRequest(aClass,Const.buildUrl(url));
}
```

}

Is it possible to get response in class? Or am trying in wrong direction.

Please suggest me.

Thank you.

Comment: pass a bundle object when u start your Gallery activity and get that in gallery activity.

Comment: Go here http://www.michenux.net/android-volley-and-gson-tutorial-797.html

Comment: One more option is that create a pojo class and save all the json data once u get the response and then later use it whenever wherever you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can refer to this using volley with gson library to make a Gson request
https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html

Comment: get the response after that you need to convert response in class using gson library

Comment: pass in the class to the GsonRequest class above the class will return the object of the class passed in previously in the success callback

Answer (score 0):

Add Gson Library in you lib folder .
this is class formate

```
public class TestData {

    public int success;
    public String message;
    public TestDatail data; 
    public class TestDatail
    {
        public int is_friend;
        public int is_following;
    }
}

Gson gs=new Gson();
return gs.fromJson(your Volley Library Response,TestData.class);
```

Comment: you need to create class as per you  response

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:Using Bundle object-->**
In my case i'm passing an array from Activity A to Activity B something like this:

```
 public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
        {
        ArrayList<Images> imagesArrayList = new ArrayList<Images>();
            try{
             if(response.has("images"))
             {
             JSONArray imagesList = response.getJSONArray("images");

              Intent i = newIntent(ActivityA.this,ActivityB.class);
                     i.putExtra("jsonArray",imagesList.toString());
                     startActivity(i);
                    }
               }catch(JSONException e){}
          }
```

And in Activity B's onCreate method check for the that passed bundle something like this:

```
    Intent i = getIntent();
    if (i.hasExtra("jsonArray")) 
    {
        String jsonArray = i.getStringExtra("jsonArray");
    try {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonArray);
        // do whatever you need with this array

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

**Method 2: Using pojo/getters & setter**

1. Create a pojo
2. Extract the required data once you receive the response using volley.
3. set it using setters of pojo.
4. start gallery activity.
5. get the data using getters of pojo.

Comment: I dont want to pass data using bundle,because there are 10 URLs and each URL will bind for different Class

Comment: Couldn't get your point. Are u facing any issues with this approach? Be specific if any.

Comment: I want to fetch/bind data for 10 activities like gallery,contact,documents.. on splash screen.

Comment: I suggest you update your question in that case or start a new thread with full details.

Comment: with 10 URLs it become difficult,so i am trying with one Url only,so i asked question like that.